# Broadcast event on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to iOS dev and wanted to learn what's Android's broadcast event equivalent in iPhone. I am trying to find Bluetooth connect/disconnect broadcast event on iOS. I am looking for Bluetooth connectivity between iPhone and any other Bluetooth based device and I want to launch my app on successful connection with Bluetooth and close the app on Bluetooth disconnect.

Example in swift would be awesome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html) and do some more research into Bluetooth notifications in iOS. You shouldn't need any examples here to figure it out.